# How to use Rubymotion to test api without timeout exception

Tags: ruby, tdd, rubymotion

I'm using Rubymotion and trying to write a test for an API method eg.

```
it "should call the api and return a result" do
   Omapi.now do |response|
     response.should.be.kind_of(Hash)
     resume
   end
   wait {}
end
```

and the method I'm calling

```
def now(&callback)           
  AFMotion::JSON.get(MY_URL) do |result|
    callback.call result
  end
end
```

Whether Im using AFMotion, Elevate or Bubblewrap, or different publicly available test endpoints - I always have the same response. ie. The api returns a result correctly but the test fails anyway with a timeout error.

```
#<AFMotion::HTTPResult:0x10d43e460 @operation=#<AFHTTPRequestOperation:0x114415c60> @object=[{"result"=>"ok"}] @error=nil>
```

**[FAILED - timeout exceeded: omapi - should call the api]**

Bacon::Error: timeout exceeded: omapi - should call the api
spec.rb:404:in `block in postponed_block_timeout_exceeded': omapi - should call the api
spec.rb:459:in`execute_block'
spec.rb:404:in `postponed_block_timeout_exceeded'

Is there any way to increase the timeout that the error refers to ?

Thanks

Comment: You have a problem in that method: it's trying to do two things, not one. My advice is to cleave that method into two: one that does the JSON.get (which you can then stub) and one that does the callback (which will return instantly during testing, because the method gets its JSON from the stub)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `wait_max` helper.

```
it "should call the api and return a result" do
  Omapi.now do |response|
    response.should.be.kind_of(Hash)
    resume
  end
  wait_max 20.0 {} # 20 seconds maximum
end
```